# What are the contributing factors, whether a fantasy empire rises or collapses in a "too vast" world?

Tags: internal-consistency, society, planets, magic

[This recent question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/86723/how-large-can-a-world-be-in-fantasy) made me wonder about the scale of fantasy worlds.

My setting is mostly a scifi/fantasy mixture, so the size of the locations are very well defined, while the impact of it on the inhabitants...not so much.

Let's start with the assumption that a kingdom is founded on an entirely uninhabited planet. The scale is most likely hundreds of millions of square kilometers.

In most cases, and slightly sticking to reality, the most predictable outcome is an enormous wave of explorative "mission" of some kind, slowly but steadily increasing the area of presence (but not necessarily area of interest) of people.

However, on small time scales, and especially with the presence of magic, and other factors, it *may* prevent the rise in technology humanity lived through during the Age of Explorations. In other worlds, globalization may not happen.

Without that, what factors contribute to the decision that whether the society as a whole collapses, or ultimately still can become somehow globalized?

*(Note: I guess [Shingeki no Kyojin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack_on_Titan) might be a great example for the former, at least for the "why they haven't globalized yet" scenario)*

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're asking.  You've invoked 'magic' but haven't described what kind of magic.  You haven't described *how* these colonists arrive or what tech level they arrive with; nor what tech level they came from.  What's the culture of these explorers/settlers?  I can't even start to answer your question without this kind of information.

Comment: Also, what time scale are we talking about?  Centuries?  Decades?

Comment: The level of technology and capability of magic is a critical element.  Without explaining that, it's hard to answer.  Easy answers would be that there are hard limits to the speed of information, but a [palantir-like](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Palant%C3%ADri) device solves that problem.  The other factor would be speed of transportation--this is what allow the US to successfully break from the British empire--sheer distance modified by time to traverse, but magical portals would eliminate this problem.

Comment: Sorry, I used "magic" tag because it was suggested instead of "fantasy" andd apparently the latter has been removed.

Comment: Your society can get fragmented, but it does not have to collapse. Look at the the age of colonization - at first, old countries vastly expanded their territory, but later most colonies got independence.

Comment: @DukeZhou Distance and time to traverse doesn't explain why Canada and Australia remained in the British Empire. They both could have made the break with as much or greater ease. Perhaps, other factors were at work in the Thirteen Colonies.

Comment: @a4android There were definitely other factors at work with the 13, but remember that Australia wasn't settled by the British until 1788, does not have the absurd bounty of the US region, and was a penal colony.  Nevertheless, within a little over 100 years, the Commonwealth of Australia is established.  Canada likely needed the UK as a bulwark against the expansionist US.  So other factors yes, but time and distance are still factors in collapse.  With the UK this also includes India and China. The Commonwealth persists, but the sun set on the British Empire.

Comment: @DukeZhou There is a wealth of factors involved. America received more convicts in the 18th century than Australia. New South Wales was a penal colony, but other parts both were & weren't. Britain did learn its lesson over the American secession, so treated its other colonies better. This is a longer topic than can dealt with adequately here. Magic portals would bring them closer to stabilize the OP's empires.

Comment: @a4android I agree with you that there are many factors, with distance being the greatest.